# Exporting Many BigQuery Tables to One

Tags: python, google-bigquery

We are kicking off bigquery queries that pull data from many tables and write to a single table. We're using Python to run the jobs with the parameters:

```
job = bq_client.run_async_query(jobname, select_query)
job.destination = bq_table
job.write_disposition = 'WRITE_APPEND'
```

500 jobs are are kicked off 20 at time. Unfortunately, periodically we run into the error:

> Exceeded rate limits: too many table update operations for this table.
>   For more information, see
>   https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors

Questions:

- Is this due to too many writes to the single destination table by the bigquery jobs/query? If so, I am surprised that Google is not throttling the write throughput of bigquery jobs internally.
- If this is the case, we have hard time gauging how many jobs can be executed in parallel because there are large differences in the dataload for each select query. What can do to avoid or handle these errors? Backoff and retry?

*Edit*:

The queries are against Google Analytics 360 data. For example:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM [{datasetname}.ga_sessions_{date}];
```

Where each dataset could be a different dataset, and querying across many dates.

I can't share the calculations against the columns, but perhaps this would be enough to come up with a way to consolidate these queries.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy

Comment: wondering: if all queries are appending to the same table, could you consolidate all queries into one?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant unfortunately we have no control over the write rate in this case since we're handling the SELECT query off to Google

Comment: @FelipeHoffa My knowledge is limited here - each select pulls from a separate dataset and table. Is it possible to consolidate these?

Comment: @KevinDeenanauth if you post a sample of your queries, we can try to write a sample of them consolidated

Comment: assuming same projection list (output columns) in all queries - how about  just simple UNION ALL for all those queries?

Answer (score 1):

assuming SELECT List is the same for all queries

for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT ... FROM `{datasetname1}.ga_sessions_{date}` UNION ALL   
SELECT ... FROM `{datasetname2}.ga_sessions_{date}` UNION ALL
...   
SELECT ... FROM `{datasetnameN}.ga_sessions_{date}`
```

for BigQuery Legacy SQL

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT ... FROM
  (SELECT ... FROM [{datasetname1}.ga_sessions_{date}]),  
  (SELECT ... FROM [{datasetname2}.ga_sessions_{date}]),  
  ...   
  (SELECT ... FROM [{datasetnameN}.ga_sessions_{date}])
```

Comment: We will give this a shot as our limitations are more predictable. However, I believe we will run into the 256KB max query length. One of our longer queries is 3.5KB which leads to a maximum of 75 union-ed queries.

Comment: you just need to regroup your queries. it is not necessarily that you really need to combine ALL your queries into one - you can just "batch" them - so instead of 500 you can have 10 or so :o)

Comment: did you have chance to try?

Comment: Just curious to know whether my use case will fall into above trouble. My use case is, I am trying to do **WRITE_TRUNCATE** for a **partitioned table** concurrently, lets say, five WRITE_TRUNCATE operation for a partitioned table in a second, **but for different partition.** Which means for a sec, I am trying to do five WRITE_TRUNCATE operation for five different partition for a table. Will my use case will lead to get `Exceeded rate limits: too many table update operations for this table rateLimitExceeded - table.write` ?

Comment: AFAIK, Partitioned table are maintained as separate table (For each partition) internally. So my assumption is, my update operation are happening in different table (different partition), so I wont get any issue like `too many table update operations for this table`, Am I right?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant ^^